# Sharepoint 2013 Error "Open with Explorer" after disabled TLS1.0

Tags: open-with-explorer

My company has planned to disabled TLS1.0 SSL2.0 SSL3.0.

So i tested my env SIT with disabled TLS1.0 and enabled TLS1.1, 1.2 then test my site collection with error "Open with Explorer" and prompt Error

"We're having a problem opening this location in File Explorer. Add this web site to your Trusted Sites list and try again"

if i enabled TLS1.0. then is fine that can open the document library with File Explorer.

Any Ideas?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already updated your machine and servers with proper updates see below; 
(– On ALL Servers in the farm and in machines consuming document libraries in Explorer view it is necessary to patch Windows)
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2016/06/28/the-unofficial-guide-for-sharepoint-2013-and-2010-working-with-tls-1-2-only/